# issue with colSums - undefined columns selected

Tags: r

Sorry it is hard to produce a reproducible example but maybe someone can help please? Usually something like this:

dummied <- dummied[,colSums(dummied) >= 30]

works fine to remove sparse dummied columns (columns contain 0s and 1s).

In some new code I get:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dummied, , colSums(dummied) >= 30): undefined columns selected
Traceback:

1. dummied[, colSums(dummied) >= 30]
2. `[.data.frame`(x, , colSums(dummied) >= 30)
3. stop("undefined columns selected")
```

Any ideas what could be the reason?

If I do:

```
colSums(dummied)
```

I still get:

```
col1 1363 col2 635 col3 34 ...
```

So colSums(dummied) seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if colSums produced any NAs? `any(is.na(colSums(dummied)))`

Comment: thanks - it appears to be the case and might be the reason?

Comment: Yes, selecting with a vector of NAs doesn't work. You can use `colSums(dummied, na.rm = T)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it seems as if you have `NAs` in your `data.frame` and thus your `colSums(dummied)` also has `NAs`. Selecting columns in a dataframe with NAs does not work. You can check with:

```
any(is.na(colSums(dummied)))
```

If that is the case, consider, why you have NAs in the data.frame. If that is not a content -wise problem  you can overcome the error by using:

```
dummied <- dummied[,colSums(dummied, na.rm = T) >= 30]
```